# Can we check if a parked domain is getting hits?

Tags: domains, multiple-domains, domain-registrar

Is there a way we can check if parked domain is receiving hits.

We have some parked domains that we are not using or are not being forwarded to other domain can we check if some one is checking website using that domain.

For example let us say we have a domain example.org as primary domain which has website associated with it. but we have another parked domain example.net which is just registered with network solution, is there a way I can know if someone is trying to use this `example.net` to access the main website?

Comment: You will need to ask your parking company. They technically can know that, but if they do really and if they want to give you this data it is totally up to them.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, I have already  contacted network solution but i am nt sure they will give us details in case they do have. On teh other side i have use alexa & SEMRush.com to get an idea, since parked domain usually are very low in traffic doesnt help much

Comment: I'm working on a redirecting service that will allow tracking of alternate domains though your site's Google Analytics.  I should be able to launch it within a month or two.   Until then, they only way to track is if the service has internal tracking you can view, or if you can implement the redirects yourself with Google Analytics UTM parameters on them.